# Some of static types forbidden from Enum initializer

Tags: java, enums

Code snippet below,

```
public enum Main {

    INSTANCE;

    private final static String STR = "abc";
    private final Map<Integer, Character> map = new HashMap<>();

    private final static int[] NUMS = { 1, 2, 3 };


    private Main() {
        for (int i = 0; i < STR.length(); i++)
            map.put(NUMS[i], STR.charAt(i)); // compiler error!
    }

    public char toChar(int i) {
        return map.get(i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Main.INSTANCE.toChar(2));
    }
}
```

It produced compiler errors below,

```
illegal reference to static field NUMS from initializer.
```

Why is `STR` allowed `static` but `NUMS` not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enum instances are initialized *before* all other fields, so you can't initialize `static` fields like that.

But there's a simple work around!

```
private static class Holder {
    final static int[] NUMS = { 1, 2, 3 };
}

private Main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < STR.length(); i++)
        map.put(Holder.NUMS[i], STR.charAt(i)); // No compiler error!
}
```

This is an example of the [Initialization-on-demand holder idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom), which makes use of the fact that inner *classes* are fully initialized *before* the class itself is initialized and which is guaranteed by the JLS to be threadsafe.

Answer (score 3):

It is not allowed as per the [language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2):

> It is a compile-time error to reference a `static` field of an enum type from constructors, instance initializers, or instance variable initializer expressions of the enum type, unless the field is a constant variable (§4.12.4).

I think the restriction is due to the fact that enum constants (i.e. the `INSTANCE`) are created during class initialization (behind the scenes it is a `static final` field), which may reference the static `NUMS` in the constructor at a time where it is still `null`, which will likely lead to an exception. This can be reproduced by substituting the `enum` with a normal class and running the code.

Comment: Any technical insights?

Comment: @sof The enum instance itself is a static variable. Allowing access to static variables could result in an initialization circularity, except for constant variables which are [initialized separately](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2-200-C.1).

Comment: @LewBloch Maybe I'm missing something but the OP is not doing that. `map` is not static. He's just accessing a `static` field.